# Call one function inside another controller function not working

Tags: magento-1.8, magento-1, controllers

Guest user enters details and click on "submit" to register. It's working fine for below code :

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('example/amasty/create1'........>
```

Here we are using the following controller action : **getUrl('example/amasty/create1**

Instead of this, if we change the controller as below and change the form, then the registration is not working anymore.

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('example/amasty/createSimpleProductAndRedirect1'....>
```

> Controllers

```
public function createSimpleProductAndRedirect1Action()
    {
        $originalProductId = $this->getRequest()->getParam("id");
        $newImagePath      = $this->getRequest()->getParam("image");
        $originalProduct   = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())->load($originalProductId);

        if ($product = $this->_create1(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_SIMPLE, true, $originalProduct, $newImagePath)) {
            $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode("Your Image Saved"));
        }        
    }

protected function _create1Action()
```

Here we replaced controller action to **example/amasty/createSimpleProductAndRedirect1**

> update

:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Amasty_Example_AmastyController::_create1()` in
```

`if ($product = $this->_create1(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_SIMPLE, true, $originalProduct, $newImagePath))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just rename `_create1Action` to `_create1` and that'll fix your issue.

NB: try to avoid using numbers in method names for good practice ;)